# Why does my ODBC Data Sources(64-bit) administrator freeze in windows 11 when I try to test an ODBC connection?

Tags: apache-spark, odbc, databricks, windows-11, simba

I need to read some data that's stored in a SQL Warehouse in Databricks. However, this data is processed inside a 3rd-party application, which doesn't have Databricks-specific drivers. Thus, we are using a generic ODBC connection, via Simba Spark.

For the past couple of days, I've been having a host of issues related to the ODBC connection itself, which I suspect are all symptoms of the same problem:

1 - Whenever I open the Data Sources manager and try to edit the DSN details, everything goes smoothly up until the point where i click the "Test" button. From past experiences, I know another window is supposed to pop-up informing if the connection was successful or not. However, this doesn't happen and the Data Sources manager simply freezes, and I cannot close it or interact with it in any way. When this happens, the only way to close it is by forcefully ending the task from inside the Task Manager. [image: The 64-bit Data Sources Administrator][image: The DSN Configuration window]

2 - If I save the connection configuration without testing, and then check the connection on the 3rd-party software, it connect successfully. However, no data comes back from any queries.

## Here's what I've tried, so far:

a - **Recheck all the information**: I've checked extensively if hostname, email, http url and password are correct and have found no errors. Furthermore, since the connection test from the 3rd-party app is successful, I don't believe this to be the issue

b - **Change the database name when trying to connect**: Also didn't work

c - **Update Windows, reinstall driver**: I have tried updating the OS, but the problem persisted. I then tried to repair the installation using the wizard, to no avail. Uninstalling, restarting the computer and reinstalling also didn't yield any positive results.

d - **Connecting from another OS**: This is the most revealing test, in my opinion. I have repeated the exact same configuration on another machine, which is running Win10, and neither issue came up. I was able to successfully test the connection in the configuration window and also managed to successfully retrieve information from the database on the 3rd-party application.

Given these tests, I believe this to be a problem with either Win11 ODBC connectivity or the interaction between the Simba Spark driver and Win11. Looking for answers, however, has proved unfruitful, as all I was able to find were references to similar problems people had on windows 7 because of a hotfix to ole32.dll back in 2014. All other results mention the ODBC Data Source administrator *crashing*, and providing some sort of error message, which isn't the case for my issue.